# Server Sent Event in grails

Tags: grails

This is my code

```
def index() {
        boolean isFirstRequest = true
        rx.stream { Observer observer ->
            while (true) {
                try {
                    if (isFirstRequest) {
                        def response = notificationService.list(params, params?.userId)
                        observer.onNext(
                                rx.render(response as JSON)
                        )
                        isFirstRequest = false
                    } else if (domainEventListener.isValidConditions()) {
                        def response = notificationService.list(params, params?.userId)
                        observer.onNext(
                                rx.render(response as JSON)
                        )
                        domainEventListener.isDataInsertionDetected = false
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Connection closed .... ${e.getLocalizedMessage()}")
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

How do I avoid using while loop, however the client should continouesly keep listening to the database events